# How can I find the max attribute in an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object

**How can I find the maximum value for the objects in my array?**

Say I have an array of objects like this:

```
$data_points = [$point1, $point2, $point3];
```

where

```
$point1 = new stdClass;
$point1->value = 0.2;
$point1->name = 'Bob';

$point2 = new stdClass;
$point2->value = 1.2;
$point2->name = 'Dave';

$point3 = new stdClass;
$point3->value = 0.8;
$point3->name = 'Steve';
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
$max = max_attribute_in_array($data_points, 'value');
```

I know I can iterate over the array with a `foreach` but is there a more elegant method using built-in functions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All examples assume that `$prop` is the name of an object property like `value` in your example:

```
function max_attribute_in_array($array, $prop) {
    return max(array_map(function($o) use($prop) {
                            return $o->$prop;
                         },
                         $array));
}
```

- `array_map` takes each array element and returns the property of the object into a new array
- Then just return the result of `max` on that array

For fun, here you can pass in `max` or `min` or whatever operates on an array as the third parameter:

```
function calc_attribute_in_array($array, $prop, $func) {
    $result = array_map(function($o) use($prop) {
                            return $o->$prop;
                        },
                        $array);

    if(function_exists($func)) {
        return $func($result);
    }
    return false;
}

$max = calc_attribute_in_array($data_points, 'value', 'max');
$min = calc_attribute_in_array($data_points, 'value', 'min');
```

If using PHP >= 7 then `array_column` works on objects:

```
function max_attribute_in_array($array, $prop) {
    return max(array_column($array, $prop));
}
```

Here is [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker)'s `array_reduce` from the comments:

```
$result = array_reduce(function($carry, $o) use($prop) {
                           $carry = max($carry, $o->$prop);
                           return $carry;
                       }, $array, -PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Comment: Ran it through my unit tests and works like a dream, thanks

Comment: Bonus points for knowing about PHP 7, alas I chose to use 5.6 for this project

Comment: Something like: `array_reduce(
    function($carry, $o) {
        $carry = max($carry, $o->$prop);
        return $carry;
    }
    $array,
    -PHP_INT_MAX
);`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$point1 = new stdClass;
$point1->value = 0.2;
$point1->name = 'Bob';

$point2 = new stdClass;
$point2->value = 1.2;
$point2->name = 'Dave';

$point3 = new stdClass;
$point3->value = 0.8;
$point3->name = 'Steve';

$data_points = [$point1, $point2, $point3];

function max_attribute_in_array($data_points, $value='value'){
    $max=0;
    foreach($data_points as $point){
        if($max < (float)$point->{$value}){
            $max = $point->{$value};
        }
    }
    return $max;
}
$max = max_attribute_in_array($data_points);
var_dump($max);
```

response:

```
float 1.2
```